# MySQL signed Order By on integer zero issue

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a signed integer set in a MyISAM table,

The query is like:

```
SELECT * from some_view ORDER BY value DESC, dateAdded DESC
```

I'm getting this order:

```
1
2
-1
-2
0
0
```

The zero values aren't seen as +/- but I need them to be greater than a negative value!!!

This is my actual query:

SELECT * FROM vw_answer sa left join vw_answer_votes av on av.answerID = sa.id WHERE sa.id  = 77 ORDER BY av.vote, dateAdded

I have the following:

```
tbl_users
tbl_solutions - Indexes tbl_users.id as authorID
tbl_solution_answers - Indexes tbl_solutions.id as solutionID
tbl_solution_answer_votes - Indexes tbl_users.id as voterID and tbl_solution_answers
as answerID
```

tbl_solution_answer_votes only has one none indexed column which contains -1 or 1 depending on the vote cast by a user. This is a signed integer.

my view when I select answers selects tbl_solution_answers and the sum(tbl_solution_answer_votes.vote)

It all works, except the ordering on signed integer.

Edit: Values in the votes table only exist if a user has voted else it simply doesn't exist. I need something like this I think:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_answers sa right join vw_answer_votes av on av.answerID = sa.id
ORDER BY av.vote > 0 desc, av.vote IS NULL, av.vote < 0 desc,  dateAdded DESC
```

Comment: What type does the `value` column have in your schema?

Comment: So you are getting 0's but you want them to not be a negative?

Comment: Tired FLOAT, DECIMAL and DOUBLE. But that shouldn't matter as it's I've declared it to be a signed integer and the value is never other than -1, 0 or 1

Comment: I meant I had "Tried" not "Tired"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are ordering on two fields, value and dateadded, try taking out your date added.

```
create table order_by_neg_test
    (`id` int(11) unsigned not null auto_increment, 
    `value` int(11) signed not null, 
     primary key (`id`)) engine=myisam default charset=utf8;
```

I inserted some random values and here are the results:

```
# No order
mysql> select * from order_by_neg_test;
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
|  1 |    45 |
|  2 |     1 |
|  3 |     0 |
|  4 |    -1 |
|  5 |    17 |
|  6 |    27 |
|  7 |    -1 |
+----+-------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

# With an order
mysql> select * from order_by_neg_test order by value desc;
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
|  1 |    45 |
|  6 |    27 |
|  5 |    17 |
|  2 |     1 |
|  3 |     0 |
|  4 |    -1 |
|  7 |    -1 |
+----+-------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Notice in the order, 0 > -1.

Comment: I need the dateAdded to be a sub order.

45 2012-01-17 then 45 2012-01-16

Comment: Gotcha. Couple of things. In the 'example' query you listed try `ORDER BY value, dateAdded DESC`. Also, the 'actual' query you listed is ordering by ASC (which occurs if you do not list anything after the ORDER BY).

Comment: I've tried many combinations already, the results always return with 0 as bottom result. Ascending/Descending aside "0" valued results should be in-between 1 and -1

Comment: I will edit question and list all involved tables if it will help?

Comment: @CraigStewart: Ya it's not possible to get 'value' to sort correctly when you add a sub-sort on 'dateAdded'. What is the reason for sorting desc on both, maybe we can step back and try a different query construct.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve something similar as this very stackoverflow page. I just up-voted your answer see now it comes up above other answers. My page is exactly the same, except a user can up and down vote between -1, 0 and 1 via ajax.

An answer has a Sum of all votes. If I have two or more answers with the same sum of votes then they need to be ordered by date

Comment: I'm an idiot, if a user's vote is 0 then i'm removing it from the vote table. So it doesn't exist!! So I guess my solution would be to get positive values, null and then negative values??

Comment: Votes are the primary sort mechanism for responses to questions on SO, then secondarily sorted by date. What I would do is pull the responses in order of current vote count DESC, then at the app layer, group them by vote count, and then sort them by date. Then you can step through using a for(each) loop and output the responses in order of vote count, sub-sorted by date.

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
ORDER BY CAST(value AS SIGNED) DESC
```

if your view screwed up the type